# Check the radio button dynamically in listview in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<p ng-repeat="item in units">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" ng-model="$parent.selectItem" ng-click="getItemValues(item)"    ng-value="{{item}} "/>
        {{item.productUnit}}
      </label><br/>
    </p>
```

Controller..

```
$scope.units.push({
        id: response[j]["productId"],
        itemPrice: response[j].productPrice,
        discountPrice: response[j].discountPrice,
        selected: true,
        productUnit: response[j].productUnit,
        unitId:response[j].unitId

      });
```

I am displaying radio buttons dynamically. 
But i want radio button should be checked . I tried many ways but not working. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons with Angular are automatically checked if the model has the same value of the object, in another words, your ng-model value needs to be the same as your ng-value, in your case **$parent.selectItem** needs to be equal as **$scope.units[someindex]**

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my answer to help you in another way

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this snippet if you still haven't found any solution.

http://embed.plnkr.co/xjakgbnevTHZwF2pCC7e/preview

```
<ion-view view-title="Radio button demo">
  <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Chosen option: {{item}}</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>  
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio ng-model="item" ng-value="i.Id" ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.Name}}</ion-radio>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "Test 1" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "Test 2" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "Test 3" }
  ];

  $scope.item = 2;
});
```